# Cannot import tflite yolov4-tiny model into flutter

Tags: flutter, tflite, yolov4

I trained the Yolo v4 tiny model using AlexeyAB's `Darknet` which was successful and inference seems to work properly. I then used hunglc007's tool  `tensorflow-yolov4-tflite` in order to convert the model to a tflite version. Here I encountered a small issue, because the FusedBatchNormV3 operator could not be found, so I followed this solution in order to add it [https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select](https://stackoverflow.com) and it worked. I managed to get a working `tflite` model (.tflite file) which using the detect script from the same repository seems to work for inference as well.

I have another flutter application where I would like to use the beforementioned model in order to do the inference directly on the mobile device. The issue is that when I am trying to import it using the official `tflite_flutter` package, I receive the following error: `Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: failed precondition)`. This is the code snippet for importing the tflite model.

```
final interpreter = await tfl.Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/yolov4-tiny-416.tflite');
```

I cannot seem to find the issue. I have added the model to the assets folder and I have also specified it in the `pubspec.yaml` file. I thought that maybe the issue could be from missing support on the TFLite Select OPs, so I also added this dependencies to the `android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.9.0'
```

That did not solve the issue unfortunately. I don't know what problem could be. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!